# I try connect arbitrium with rpc in ethers@v6, but get empty obj

Tags: arbitrum

```
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(
    'https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc',
  )
  console.log({ provider, chainId })
```

// result: { provider: JsonRpcProvider {}, chainId: 42161 }

version ethers@v5.7 works fine